# Why is gives Error CS0120

Tags: c#

I know that it a [common error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s35hcfh7.aspx). But I would like to know why my code gives this error.

> The VS gives the error CS0120  C# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

```
class LoginsAtivosDAO

        public static List<LoginAtivo> getList() {
        return contexto.LoginsAtivos.ToList();
    }

class List_Users_Form

private void atualizaLista() {
        LoginDao dao = new LoginDao();
        List<string> lista = new List<string>();
        foreach(LoginAtivo u in LoginsAtivosDao.getList() ) {
            lista.Add(dao.getUsuario(u.UsuarioID).Nome);
        }

        listBox1.DataSource = lista;
    }
```

Comment: what is `contexto.LoginsAtivos` where it is defined?

Comment: it is a `DBContext` and it is defined in the class `LoginsAtivosDAO`

Comment: What don't you understand? Did you read the docs you linked to?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes, I did. What I don't understand is the reason of the error. It seems correct. Why is wrong with this call ?

Comment: Which line raises the error?

Comment: If you understand what causes the error, can you explain why you think your code is correct?

Comment: Because I am making a call for a static method and I do not change it

Comment: The term `static` does not mean "I´m, not changing anything". It means that this member (method or property) belongs to no single instance of this class but to every instance. Thus you won´t need an instance to use this member.

Comment: I can´t see anything whorng on your code except some missing paranthesis and the fact that your class is called `LoginsAtivosDAO` and you call `getList` on `LoginsAtivosDao`. Furthermore: what is `contexto`? It has to be `static` to be used in your method as un-lucky already mentions.

Comment: but this is just for the post. I just wanted someone to review my code. TY.
@HimBromBeere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you have a class called `LoginsAtivosDAO` and a variable called `LoginsAtivosDao` (be it a spelling-mistake or whatever).

However the member `contexto` seems to cause your problem. It should be static within your class `LoginsAtivosDAO`:

```
class LoginsAtivosDAO
{
    static DBContext contexto = ...;

    public static List<LoginAtivo> getList() 
    {
        return contexto.LoginsAtivos.ToList();
    }
}

class List_Users_Form 
{
    private void atualizaLista() {
        LoginDao dao = new LoginDao();
        List<string> lista = new List<string>();
        foreach(LoginAtivo u in LoginsAtivosDao.getList() ) {
            lista.Add(dao.getUsuario(u.UsuarioID).Nome);
        }
        listBox1.DataSource = lista;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `contexto.LoginsAtivos` is a non-static field/property and you are trying to access them inside a static Method. Such operation is not permitted. What you can avoid this in two ways:

1. Remove `static` keyword from the method signature:

   ```
   public List<LoginAtivo> getList() 
   {
       return contexto.LoginsAtivos.ToList();
   }
   ```
2. Make `contexto.LoginsAtivos` as static.

> **Note :** If you spend some time to read the [attached link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s35hcfh7.aspx) to the question, then this question will not raise. The answer is clearly stated there as "In order to use a non-static field, method, or property, you must first create an object instance."

Comment: the code above show the only call that I make for function getList() of this class . Theoretically, I am not changing the variable

Comment: @VictorHenrique : have you tried removing the static from the method signature?

Comment: Yes. But I still wanna know why the reason of error.

Comment: Reason is explained in that attached link. `In order to use a non-static field, method, or property, you must first create an object instance.`

Comment: "changing the variable" has nothing to do with it. You can't *access* a non-static field from a static context - either reading or writing. Think about this: How would the program know which instance you want?